# How to escape unicode syntax (u'foo') in JSON string?

Tags: jquery, python, json, unicode

I'm passing a JSON String from the server to a Django template.  When I assign the JSON String to a jQuery variable, I'm getting unicode syntax.

Py:

```
# Call Facebook Graph API to get list of Friends.
result = facebook.GraphAPI(
            user.access_token).get_connections('me', 'friends')
friends = result["data"]
```

jQuery/Django template:

```
var friends = {{friends}};
```

Inspecting the assignment in Firebug:

```
[
      {
         u'name': u'Joe Smith',
         u'id': u'6500000'
      },
      {
         u'name': u'Andrew Smith',
         u'id': u'82000'
      },
      {
         u'name': u'Dora Smith',
         u'id': u'97000000'
      }
]
```

Comment: I take it you're getting an error here? It might be clearer what the problem is if you tell us more about the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert `friends` to JSON on the server side. You're seeing the Python representation, which looks like kind of like JSON sometimes but isn't.

Comment: This answer is exactly right. `friends` is a Python list of Python dictionaries, not the JSON string you think it is.

Answer (score 2):

As Brian Goldman points out, the `friends` variable isn't a JSON string, like you say, but a Python object, which looks enough like JSON when printed out to pass for it, sometimes.

You need to convert it to proper JSON before passing it to the template. At the top of your `views.py`, put this line

```
from django.utils import simplejson
```

And then pass `simplejson.dumps(friends)` to the template, rather than just `friends`.

Whatever you do, just don't try to construct the JSON by hand in the template :) If you don't fully control the source data (and you don't; in this case it comes from Facebook) you will have no end of troubles with your template.

Answer (score 1):

When python represents a string, `u'123'` for example then it means the string is unicode, there would be no real advantage to escaping this or removing it, it still behaves like a normal string

Comment: unless I'm misunderstanding, it seems like the advantage would be generating json data that jquery actually accepts.